# Things to do in 12 hour Night layover in Dubai?

Tags: sightseeing, layovers, dubai, night-transport

I am looking for things to do in Dubai at night. I will be travelling in mid-June and will be arriving at 12.30 am. My connecting flight is at 1 pm next afternoon. I have glanced through the criteria for visa and I qualify to apply. I want to know what are the things that can be done in the time I have, provided I reach airport by 11 am for my connecting flight. I am more interested in sight seeing than sitting in pubs. Can anyone please guide me? Also what mode of transportation do you recommend considering a tight budget?

Comment: my layover is longer and I have a window in the morning.

Comment: @Abhi, there's plenty to do in the morning but not much in the evening at 1am. You could get dinner somewhere—a few places will be open at this hour, it is not unusual to eat late, although 1 am is pushing it, and the temperature will be comfortable (ish) outside at this time (about 30 ºC). Other than that I'd suggest getting a hotel somewhere. I believe there is a night bus but the metro from the airport closes at midnight.

Comment: Are there any night tours from the hotels near the airport which I can avail ?